# Thread not printing everything after notifyAll in java

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized, notify

```
class Lock implements Runnable{
  int i=0;
  public synchronized void run(){
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("t1") && i == 5)
         {try { this.wait();} catch(InterruptedException ie){}}
        System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" ");
        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("t3") && i == 9)
         this.notifyAll();
  }
 }
}
public class ThreadLock {
 public static void main(String[] args){   
  Lock l = new Lock();
  Thread t1 = new Thread(l);
  Thread t2 = new Thread(l);
  Thread t3 = new Thread(l);
  t1.setName("t1");
  t2.setName("t2");
  t3.setName("t3");
  t1.start();
  t2.start();
  t3.start();
 }
}
```

Output is:
t1 t1 t1 t1 t1 t3 t3 t3 t3 t3 t3 t3 t3 t3 t3 t1 t2 t2 t2 t2 t2 t2 t2 t2 t2 t2

t1 is not printing all 10 times after calling notifyAll method.
I ran it many times but every time t1 is printed only 6 times.
Why t1 is not printing all 10 times?
please reply soon

Comment: Even after you have changed `i` to be a local variable, this program is not _guaranteed_ to always print "t1" ten times.  It is possible in theory for the t3 thread to finish its task and call `notifyAll()` before the t1 task calls `wait()`.  If that happens, the `wait()` call will never return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is an instance variable. It's shared by all the threads. It should be a local variable.

When the first thread is awakened, it reacquires the lock, prints its name, increments i, and reevaluates if `i < 10`. But since the other threads have set `i` to 10 already, the loop stops.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are sharing the same index `i` between threads, so when the thread t3 exists and t1 is awaken index `i` will be `10` and the for loop in thread t1 will exit.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling .join() on each after starting each thread to make sure each thread completes before the program exits?

Comment: Any live non-daemon thread should prevent the jvm from terminating, but stdout could be closed when main returns.

Answer (score 0):

While the correct answer is already given by JB Nizet, you might wonder, why this only affects `t1`:
Every thread is reseting `i`, when the run method (which is synchronized) is called.

But the moment you RETURN the execution of t1 - it's not going to reset `i`, since the thread has already started the `for`-loop.

```
   i | output
   0 | t1 (FIRST iteration of t1 -> Setting i=0)
   1 | t1
   2 | t1
   3 | t1
   4 | t1
   5 | t1
   0 | t3 (FIRST iteration of t3 -> Setting i = 0)
   1 | t3
   2 | t3
   3 | t3
   4 | t3
   5 | t3
   6 | t3
   7 | t3
   8 | t3
   9 | t3
   0 | t2 (FIRST iteration of t2 -> Setting i = 0)
   1 | t2
   2 | t2
   3 | t2
   4 | t2
   5 | t2
   6 | t2
   7 | t2
   8 | t2
   9 | t2
   9 | t1 (t1 restored, but i=9 now. One more output, program done)
```

Note: That's at least what is happening for your described output. I think it might also be possible, that t2 is executed before t3, leading to a different output.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. 'i' was outside of synchronized method so now I made 'i' local variable of for loop. 'for(int i=0;i<10;i++)'. now its printing t1 all 10 times.